# Karate + Gatling: exitHereIfFailed not working

Tags: karate

I have this simulation:

```
class TestSimulation extends Simulation {
  val protocol = karateProtocol()
  val scn = scenario("test")
    .exec(karateFeature("classpath:test1.feature"))
    .exitHereIfFailed
    .exec(karateFeature("classpath:test2.feature"))

  setUp(
    scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(protocol)
  )
}
```

test1.feature:

```
Feature: Test 1
  Scenario:
    * print '1'
    * assert 1 == 2
```

test2.feature:

```
Feature: Test 2
  Scenario:
    * print '2'
```

Because test1.feature is failing, I expect Gatling to stop the scenario there and not print '2', but in the logs I see:

```
Simulation simulations.TestSimulation started...
05:50:06.217 [DEBUG] i.g.c.c.i.o.OpenWorkload - Start user #1
05:50:06.219 [DEBUG] i.g.c.c.i.o.OpenWorkload - Injecting 1 users in scenario test, continue=false
05:50:06.220 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - StoppedInjecting
05:50:06.411 [DEBUG] c.j.j.i.p.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $
05:50:06.425 [INFO ] c.intuit.karate - [print] 1
05:50:06.429 [ERROR] c.intuit.karate - assertion failed: assert evaluated to false: 1 == 2
05:50:06.443 [DEBUG] c.j.j.i.p.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $
05:50:06.445 [INFO ] c.intuit.karate - [print] 2
05:50:06.445 [DEBUG] i.g.c.a.Exit - End user #1
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate (probably) doesn't support `.exitHereIfFailed`.

Perhaps you can contribute code.

EDIT - should work in 1.0: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1382

Comment: I'm looking for a workaround. Maybe I can use the .doIf from Gatling using some flag in the session. Can I modify the Gatling session inside a karate feature or can I return a result in karateFeature()?

Comment: @italktothewind just use a java singleton (lock or synchronize if needed) and you can do whatever you want. but I think you should be able to modify JSON in the session, may be worth trying - I haven't

Comment: I couldn't find out how to modify the Gatling session inside a karate scenario nor from a karateFeature execution :(

Comment: @italktothewind created a roadmap item. I hope someone picks this up for hacktoberfest: https://github.com/intuit/karate/projects/3#card-44762585